# Do dom events fire in a defined order?

Tags: javascript, dom

For example, given the following code, when I first click the parent and then click the child element, the events always seem to fire in this order `MOUSEDOWN`, `FOCUSOUT`, `FOCUSIN`:

html

```
<div
 id="parent"
 tabindex="0"
 style="background-color: blue; height: 100px; width: 100px;">
 <div
   id="child"
   tabindex="0"
   style="background-color: red; height: 50px; width: 50px;">
 </div>
</div>
```

js

```
var node = document.getElementById('parent');

node.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
 console.log("MOUSEDOWN");
});

node.addEventListener('focusin', function () {
 console.log("FOCUSIN");
});

node.addEventListener('focusout', function () {
 console.log("FOCUSOUT");
});
```

This appears to be true for IE11 as well. Is this just an implementation coincidence or is there an officially defined order event listeners for each event type will be triggered in? Can I rely on `mousedown` always coming before `focusin` or `focusout`?

Comment: Use `'` or `"` in your code.

Comment: I don't see anything in the spec regarding order. That being said, if it matters, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez sorry was copied in and quotes got messed up. fixed!